# How to let a plot start at a certain point x instead of at x = 0

Tags: r

I have a line that I need to plot after another line in R such that they go over into each other. The line at the end needs to be red. How can I make sure that when I use plot(....) function for the first line and lines(....) for the second data that this second data coming from lines(....) plots at x = a instead of beginning at x = 0?

Answer (score 0):

Make the values for second data from 1 to a as NA

data2[1:a] = NA